# Create table columns as variables in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I am running a query with a while loop that creates an array of the column names

```
while($ContactLookup_Row = mysql_fetch_array($ContactLookup_Rs)) {
        $ContactLookup_Results[] = array(
        'sequence'=>$ContactLookup_Row["sequence"], 
        'forename'=>$ContactLookup_Row["forename"],
        'surname'=>$ContactLookup_Row["surname"]
         );
    }
```

How can I make the loop add all the column names as their own variables without having to type them all out manually?

Should I put `$ContactsLookup_Results[]= array(` before the while loop. And then `);` after the while loop

And then I'm not sure about within the loop?

I want it to look like:

```
'ColumnName'=>$ContactLookup_Row["ColumnName"]
```

With a , on the end of each one but not the last one

Comment: Obligatory: [**don't use `mysql_` functions anymore**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Can you post how the resulting array should then look like? Becouse I don't know what you mean...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
while($ContactLookup_Row = mysql_fetch_array($ContactLookup_Rs)) {
        $ContactLookup_Results[] = $ContactLookup_Row;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$sql="DESCRIBE $_table_name";

$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

    $columns[$data['Field']]=$data['Field'];

}
```